# Reading words from a file doesn't work as supposed to

Tags: c, file, io

I am trying to read words from a file. The file is a txt and contain some words.In my text i have around 10 words. Evertime although i run the code i only get the first word. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define WORDLEN 30

/* Given the name of a file, read and return the next word from it, 
or NULL if there are no more words */

char *getWord(char *filename)  {
    char formatstr[15], *word;
    static FILE *input;
    static int firstTime = 1;
    if (firstTime) { 
        input = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (input == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR: Could not open file \"%s\"\n", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
        firstTime = 0;
    }
    word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*WORDLEN);
    if (word == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation error in getWord\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(formatstr, "%%%ds", WORDLEN-1);
    fscanf(input, formatstr, word);
    if (feof(input)) {
        fclose(input);
        firstTime = 1;
        return NULL;
    }


    printf("%s", word)
    return word;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "tinydict.txt";
    getword(a)
}
```

Do i need perhaps to add all of them in one loop? and if yes will i have to use `EOF`?

Comment: would it be better to use `fgets` instead?

Comment: i could definitely do that but atm i am trying to do it using `fscanf`. I know i can do it other way too i just want to make it the `fscanf` way

Comment: You forgot to put repeatedly call `fscanf()`, it only read one word at a time. Put everything inside a loop.

Comment: `fscanf` only "scans" one time; just like your `malloc` line, for example, the function is called only once, not 'continuously' or something like that. Read a manual.

Comment: @Jongware i know that already. i know i have to put all this in a loop but i can't seem to able to find how to put them in a loop and keep reading the words until i reach the end of the file

Comment: while (!feof(input)){ ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you loop like this -

```
 while(fscanf(input, formatstr, word)==1){   // this will read until fscanf is successful
   printf("%s", word);
 }
```

Also , you print `word` in function itself then why do you `return` it from function and when called in `main` you don't assign it to anything , you just write -

```
 getword(a);
```

in `main`. Then why not declare function as `void` ?

Comment: i am just trying out to see the outcome. It should return `word` since it's a function i am later going to use

Comment: @Korpel Okay ,then assign function's `return` to `char *` .

Comment: @Korpel Yeah , I got it what you meant  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The loop could be written like this:

```
while (!feof(input)){
    if (fscanf(input, formatstr, word) == 1){
        printf("%s", word);
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of using `firstTime`?

Comment: @ameyCU seriously, the OP is clearly, a beginner and no need to overload with that semantics of it.

Comment: Okay , I would withdraw it , but clearly I don't see reason to practice it :-)

Comment: Yes indeed i am a beginner and i am trying to learn better C programming. The beginning is hard i gotta admit but i want to be better so really thank  you guys for helping me out even with my noobish questions